# MonoTouch - cross-platform API abstraction layer?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I understand that with MonoTouch and MonoDroid that you develop against the native UI layer, which is a good thing. However, I was wondering if there were any cross platform Mono API layers for features such as camera, location, storage, notifications etc... ?

PhoneGap supplies a JavaScript a abstraction layer that does just this. Is there a Mono equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an official monomobile api project from xamarin - that provides camera, contacts and gps abstractions, plus there are discussions (but not firm roadmaps) about extending this further. See http://blog.xamarin.com/2011/11/22/introducing-the-xamarin-mobile-api/ for an intro

Beyond that:

- some api's exist cross platform from the start - eg isolated storage can be used on all platforms.
- I've seen a few other GitHub projects started - eg chrisntr's mono extensions
- I've written a few abstractions (e.g. File, gps, camera) in http://GitHub.com/slodge/mvvmcross

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across [MonoDroid.Dialog](https://github.com/kevinmcmahon/MonoDroid.Dialog). I have yet to use it, but if it is as easy as MonoTouch.Dialog to do tables then I will be very happy with it.